# Changing item ID from INT to BIGINT

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla-k2

I use Joomla 2.5 and latest K2.
If i change the K2 item ID field from INT to BIGINT, will i got any complications or functional issues?

I need to input IDs with 10 digit length, but i can't input ID's larger than 2147483647.

Thanks
Egon

Comment: I am curious why you would need to mess with the item ID field. Why not use an extra field to store the long ID and leave the item ID alone? You risk having update issues making changes to the DB.

Comment: i'm building a book shop based on k2. the book data will be updated with a tool which uses item id for identifying, which item is to update. i have already done as you mean (this data is already in extrafield) by for updates issue i must have books isbn number not only as extrafield data, but as item id too. and isbn number are from 10 to 13 signs long. after i get all codings done (there are some more core changes), i will freeze the code and will not run into update issues.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla seems not to be supporting BIGINT as ID's.

Source: http://community.joomla.org/featured-articles/did-you-know/471-how-to-break-your-joomla-website.html

Comment: good find, however this was written in 2010 when Joomla 1.5 was about. I'm not entirely sure but things might have changed in Joomla 2.5+

Comment: Well, here is written, Joomla does support BIGINT: [link](http://www.itoctopus.com/maximum-number-of-articles-categories-and-users-on-joomla). If i change any field from INT to BIGINT, is it enough to make the same changes in all joining tables?

Comment: Oh right, sorry for misleading then. I completely forgot to check the article date.